# Маркер последовательности байтов

Tags: unicode

Хочу понять что такое маркер последовательности байтов и в чем его плюсы и минусы. Я в этом полный новичок и хочу в этом разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про этот маркер отлично написано на [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Мое мнение на этот счет:

**"Плюсы"**:

1. Программы могут однозначно отображать Unicode не путаясь в кодировках.

**"Минусы"**:

1. Часто возникают проблемы при вставке одних файлов в другие (например при подключении исходных текстов программ). Появление BOM при этом может "ломать" содержание;
2. Не все редакторы и просмотрщики поддерживают этот маркер.